# Tangent vectors to geodesics on the $2$-sphere

Tags: geometry, vectors

Consider two points on the $2$-sphere as well as the geodesic between these two points (say points $A$, and $B$). Is it true that if I take a vector $u$ tangent to this geodesic at $A$, that it will be in the span of $A$ and $B$, and if so why?

This came about in the proof of the cosine of the vertex angles in a spherical triangle on the 2-sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are antipodal points (like the North and the South pole), then no (just picture this configuration and it will be obvious).

Let us assume then that $A$ and $B$ are linearly independent in $\Bbb R^3$. Since bijective linear maps preserve (in-)dependence, perform a rotation in $\Bbb R^3$ in order to bring that geodesic into a horizontal position, like the Equator on the Earth. Then $A$ and $B$ will belong the the Equatorial plane $\Pi$ and, being linearly independent, will be a basis of it. Since $u$ is tangent to that geodesic, and the geodesic is contained in $\Pi$, it follows that $u \in \Pi$, which was $\text{span } \{A, B\}$.

Comment: $u$ being tangent to the geodesic implies it is in the plane??

Comment: @TheMathNoob: To be more detailed: $u$ is tangent to a curve which is in $\Pi$, therefore in particular $u$ is tangent to $\Pi$. Then yes, it necessarily belongs to $\Pi$, there is no other way.

Comment: @TheMathNoob: Yes, provided we work in vector geometry. If you have a vector space $V$ and a linear subspace $W$, then $u \in V$ is tangent to $W$ if and only if $u \in W$ - the two are synonymous. If you are working in affine geometry, you must require the vector to have the "tail" "attached" to the plane - which is the case here, because the "tail" of $u$ is $A$, which belongs to $\Pi$.